# What are the limits of Brandon Stark's greensight abilities?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Is there any suggestions or evidence of limits to Brandon Stark's greensight abilities scrolling back and forward in time and 'jumping' in space in the TV series?

Can he, for example as the newly appointed Three Eyed Raven, witness past and future events such as the doom of Valyria or uncover the secrets of creation or see the outcome of a war?

Comment: We don't know. As of now he seems capable of anything on weirwood.net

Comment: I've edited it to make it LESS opinion based, and cuz I want to answer it :)

Comment: @Edlothiad no problem,  looks good

Comment: **Warning: TV Tropes Link**: [Somewhat related](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheOmniscient). I feel like Bran also *knows what the plot needs him to know*. Couldn't find a link to that trope though...

Comment: I don't think he can see all places past, present, and future **all the time**. It seems like he has to choose a specific place and time and look at what event occurred there and then. If he could see all events in the present everywhere, then he would not have needed to send out ravens to spy for him north of the wall to locate the Night King and the army of the dead.

Comment: If this has answered your question feel free to accept. If it's not good enough please provide some criticism

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## He seems to be limited to the near past

As far as we've seen, without the Three-eyed Raven, Bran has been able to Warg as he wants, but has never mentioned anything further back than Lyanna's wedding (if I remember correctly). However with the fully "trained" Three-eyed Raven, they were able to go all the way back to the Age of Heroes (to witness the creation of the first White Walker).

One thing that we need to notice is the more recent ones Bran has done without the presence of a Weirwood right next to him. The travels with the Three-eyed raven, and others on his way south, always took place next to a Weirwood. It would seem in the show canon, up until late in season 7, he wasn't shown being able do any form of greensight/time travel without a Weirwood. This trend is broken when he is sat in his room and sees the wedding between Lyanna and Rhaegar after Sam mentions it.

Another "missing Weirwood" is in the memories he's visiting. At the Tower of Joy, although Bran might be by a Weirwood in the present, there's no distinct Weirwoods in the Tower of Joy scene and I believe in the book canon there are no Weirwood trees that far south (in Dorne). Furthermore, in the Throne Room, there is again no Weirwood, yet Bran was able to witness Petyr talk about ladders and their chaos.

In conclusion, it seems at the height of his power, the Three-eyed Raven is unlimited by how far he can travel back, however as far as we know requires a Weirwood to see the distant past, both in the present and in the past. The nearer past Bran seems to be able to see regardless of proximity to a Weirwood (such as Petyr's scheming and the Tower of Joy scenes).

Comment: Good answer, thanks.